# Android: Get specific rows from database

Tags: android, mysql

I have a database of about 200 rows and i was wondering how to get rows from ids 50 to 75. Im using the following code to retrieve all the rows from the database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DETAILS;
     try {
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
         try {
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {
                    Log.d("Data", cursor.getString(1));
                        Log.d("Data", cursor.getString(3)));
                    Log.d("Data", cursor.getString(4)));
                    Log.d("Data", cursor.getString(5)));
                 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
             }

         } finally {
             try {
                 cursor.close(); 
             } catch (Exception ignore) {

             }
         }
     } finally {
         try {
             db.close();
         } catch (Exception ignore) {

         }
     }
```

Thanks,
Sahil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use where statement like:

```
 WHERE ids >= 50 AND ids <= 75
```

Comment: Upvoting, but I think the variable is called ROWID instead of ids.  Or maybe it can go by both, I know SQLite does some aliasing there.

Comment: thanks @GabeSechan, I have use `ids` because OPs statement : "how to get rows from **ids** 50 to 75" , i thought that one column in table is ids.